# What gets run on an "exit" and how can I not run Object Finalizers on exit ? Ruby

Tags: ruby

What gets run on an "exit" and how can I not run Object Finalizers on exit ?

Note: I do want to use exit!.

Comment: Are you missing the word "not" in your "Note:"? If you are, why don't you want to use `exit!`?

Comment: If you are wanting to not run the exit handlers and still return "success" to the operating system then you can just run "exit!(true)", which overrides the default false status of "exit!"

Comment: What's your goal with not running object finalizers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"exit" runs code blocks that are defined with:

```
at_exit { run_this }
```

and also any Object Finalizers.

You can undefine an Object Finalizer by tapping into ObjectSpace and using "undefine_finalizer", but I would not recommend you do so.  Accessing and destroying object via ObjectSpace can cause odd behaviors (also JRuby does not utilize ObjectSpace unless you explicitly tell it to with the "+O" flag)

undefining an ObjectFinalizer looks like:

```
ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(obj)
```

Again, delving into the Ruby internals like this can cause odd behavior in your application, make sure you know what you are doing before releasing something like this into a production application.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/ObjectSpace.html